# Problems to receive data from angularjs ajax

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I have a http request with ajax as below :

```
$http.post('/pharma/laravel/public/insert', {msg:'hello word!'})
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("fail");
  });
```

I can receive information from server (in success function status is 200), I can also to send data to server, but I can't to read data on server. $_POST is a empty array. Why ?

To be more clear on server i have just this:

```
var_dump ($_POST);
```

and the result that is sent back (in success function) is an empty array

```
array(0) { }
```

Another specification:

When I making http request with AngularJS in Console -> Network in Headers tab I have a section Request Payload when I can to see the data which was send by ajax in red. Important is that I don't have the section Form Data, and in Preview tab is displayed same info  array(0) { }

When I making same  http request with JQuery in Console -> Network in Headers tab I don't have section Request Payload this time but instead I can to find section Form Data with the data which was send by ajax and in Preview tab is displayed that why should to be : array(1) { ["msg"]=> string(11) "hello word!"}

Also in both cases status is 200 and i don't have another redirect.

Comment: Are you saying `data` is an empty array?

Comment: Could you post the server side code? Your POST line looks correct on the client side.

Comment: are you using url rewrite? redirecting from one page to another? (e.g redirecting from domain.com to www.domain.com). this may cause clearing the $_POST array.

Comment: Usually a redirect which basically "converts" a post request to a get request and thus your post data is gone.

Comment: I do not understand. Why if I do a jquery ajax with same url and same date everything goes perfectly. I receive on server all date. But with angular ajax I don.'t receive data on server.

Comment: Inspect the network tab in your dev tools and verify that the request is a post request, contains the data and that there is no redirect.